# mysql FIND_IN_SET returned an empty result set

Tags: mysql, sql, find-in-set

I have the following input table "*eastate_facilitylist*":

| eastate_id | facilityList |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,3,4 |
| 2 | 1,3,4 |
| 3 | 1 |

I want to select the "*eastate_id*" values that have a value inside it, so I've crafted the following query:

```
SELECT eastate_id FROM `eastate_facilitylist` 
WHERE ( FIND_IN_SET(3, facilityList))
```

Problem is that it returns an empty result set.

I'm using MySQL 5.7.31.

How can I fix my query?

Comment: I suspect that there are spaces between the numbers in the lists of facilityList.

Comment: yes, spaces between the text seems likely, but still you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad  as FIND_IN_SET costs much performamce

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=449073d6e12f9f46c7cf415374e358ba